# configuring rspec-rails generators

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I want to configure rpsec-rails generators so that I can for example disable view and controller tests or manually replace fixtures with factories. I read the documentation, blog posts and ask questions on rspec IRC channel, but I found no good answer. suppose I want to disable the view specs. I should do something like:

```
config.generators do |g|
  g.test_framework :rspec,
    views: false
end
```

My question is where can I find list of all available option like 'views'?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here is the list of all options which I know for `Rspec`:

```
config.generators do |generate|
  generate.test_framework  :rspec,
        fixtures: true,
        view_specs: false,
        helper_specs: false,
        routing_specs: false,
        controller_specs: false,
        request_specs: false
   generate.fixture_replacement :factory_girl, dir: "spec/factories"
end
```

Example with a friendly sintax for rails 5.++

```
# config/application.rb
config.generators do |g|
  g.test_framework :rspec
  g.helper_specs false
  g.controller_specs false
  g.view_specs false
  g.routing_specs false
  g.request_specs false
end
```

The list of options can be found in [RSpec Rails](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails) library.

- [Options for rspec-rails 5.1](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/blob/5-1-maintenance/lib/generators/rspec/scaffold/scaffold_generator.rb#L17-L21).
- [Latest options from main, but obviously, may be moved.](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/blob/main/lib/generators/rspec/scaffold/scaffold_generator.rb)

Comment: That is what Aaron Sumner says in his book and blog, too. But where did you or Aaron find these options? These are not well documented.

Comment: Here is where these options are currently defined in the code: https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/blob/1fe6c2e8a56f46ae4c2f13ffa0733cce3b717c2d/lib/generators/rspec/scaffold/scaffold_generator.rb#L17-L21